# Simple Commerce, capture user information

Tags: commerce

I need to create a channel which editors can upload different events to and where user can then enter their details and pay to attend these events.

I was going to use channels and simple commerce to enable users to pay for these events but we'd also want to capture some information from the user such as name, email, etc. What the easiest way to capture their information?

Thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 1):

You should use Custom Profile Data Tag to get all the user's data. See doc from here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/#custom-profile-data-tag